# C# - DataGrid -> DataGridCell -> Background -> partial draw

Tags: c#, datagrid

Can you help me how to partially draw background color in DataGridCell, please?

**What I would like to do:**
Cell 1 has value 100, Cell 2 has value 50.
Cell 1 Background will be filled as Blue. And Cell 2 background will be filled/rendered in blue only as half, other half will be default background.

Any ideas how to do this?
[I would like to do it like on this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK0Ja.jpg)

Note: I have to use DataGrid control, not DataGridView form. In DataGridView it is easy. But problem is to do it in DataGrid.

Comment: I think there's a DataGrid in WPF and ASP.Net, and in old WinForms.  Add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cell template and assign its background using a dependency property. Below in the code snipplet I assume you use a TextBox to show values and define the Backgroound of theTextBox in your code behind. Thus you have full control when defining value dependent background colors.

```
<DataGrid ... >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn >
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
              <TextBlock Text="your header" />
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding your data}" 
                 Background="{Binding ElementName=your Win/Class, Path=DepPropBackgrd}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was my guess too. But I didn't found any documention how the templates works. I am not familier how the XAML works properly here. Can you show me how to do it in C#, please? Another thing, I need to code it though 3rd party script ninjatrader.com/support/helpGuides/nt8/?ninjascript.htm . So there are some boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. It is easy and total different way. Just have to create own brush.
Example:

```
Pen pen = new Pen();
pen.Thickness = 0.0;
pen.Brush = Brushes.Transparent;

RectangleGeometry geometryRectangle = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0,0, 50, 50));
GeometryDrawing geometry = new GeometryDrawing(brush, pen, geometryRectangle);
                
DrawingBrush myDrawingBrush = new DrawingBrush();
myDrawingBrush.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
myDrawingBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Right;
myDrawingBrush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center;
myDrawingBrush.Drawing = geometry;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small hack you requested. The XAML part is straight forward

```
<Window x:Class="DGColor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="WinDGRid"
    Loaded="WinDGRid_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="200">
  <Grid>
      <DataGrid x:Name="dgColor" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="2" >
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                  <!-- Set header of DataTable Column -->
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Value" Width="200" />
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=colval}"  
                                 Background="{Binding Path=color}" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here ist the Code behind part.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void WinDGRid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Colorvalues = new ObservableCollection<Colorvalue>
        {
            new Colorvalue{colval = 25, color= new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 25))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 50, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 50))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 75, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 75))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 100, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 100))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 125, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 125))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 150, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 150))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 175, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 175))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 200, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 200))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 225, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 225))},
            new Colorvalue{colval = 250, color=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 250))},
        };
        dgColor.ItemsSource = Colorvalues;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Colorvalue> Colorvalues
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Colorvalue>)GetValue(ColorvaluesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorvaluesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorvaluesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Colorvalues", typeof(ObservableCollection<Colorvalue>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
public class Colorvalue
{
    public int colval {get; set;}
    public SolidColorBrush color { get; set; }
}
```

Happy coding